# R - Forecast values using last known and rate in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, forecasting

I have a dataset that consists of a known volume over time with a max & min rate of change aggregated over previous periods. The `max_RelChange` column is the relative change of the aggregate maximum for each day regardless of year. The column has been added here to calculate future values but isn't necessarily what I want to report.

```
>head(arrange( set3[,c(1,7,10,17, 19)], desc(EFFECTIVE_DATE)))
  EFFECTIVE_DATE      STD_INVENTORY_VOLUME Vintage   max_RelChange max_forecast  
1 2019-03-25 09:00:00                   NA Predicted      0.000592 NA          
2 2019-03-24 09:00:00                   NA Predicted      0.00186  NA          
3 2019-03-23 09:00:00                   NA Predicted      0.00251  NA          
4 2019-03-22 09:00:00                   NA Predicted      0.00307  NA          
5 2019-03-21 09:00:00                   NA Predicted      0.00262  NA          
6 2019-03-20 09:00:00                   NA Predicted      0.00216  NA
```

[Graph of the data to illustrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAL7J.png)

The predicted value would pick up where the red line ends and change based on the last `STD_INVENTORY_VOLUME` value and the `max_RelChange` which denotes how the value should change.

The column would be calculated row by row using something similar to the equation below.

```
lag(set3$STD_INVENTORY_VOLUME ,1) * set3$max_RelChange + lag(set3$STD_INVENTORY_VOLUME , 1)
```

I have the dataset setup with future dates and the vintage denotes that the value is predicted. Currently, future volumes are NULL. I'd imagine you'd need to set up a function and iterate over the rows so you have a previous value to work with but can't get the syntax working. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you please show an example of the output you'd like to create?

Comment: Also, I expected `min_RelChange` to reflect a rate of change in `STD_INVENTORY_VOLUME` (and thereby be the basis for your ongoing forecast), but I can't figure out the relationship in the given data. (For instance, `STD_INVENTORY_VOLUME` is always decreasing, but `min_RelChange` sometimes is >0.)

Comment: I updated the post to hopefully answer your questions.